# I'm passing a list of JSON file is not getting display in the Android application

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I was Passing a this JSON  http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cacde192f000078003a93bb

i was trying to print a just a category_name

I'm not able to get the data list , when i pass the object with out the data list just like  http://www.mocky.io/v2/5cb859344c0000092ed3d4df

`````
   private Category_name category_name;

   public Category_name getCategoryName() {
       return category_name;
   }
}

   public class Category_name {
       @SerializedName("category_name")
       public String name;

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }
   }````

i can access that through the NewAdapter.java
with the following code

@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Log.e("Its coming","NewAdapter");
       ApiObject apiObject = apiObjectList.get(position);
       holder.title.setText(apiObject.getCategoryName().getName());
   }

with the same  code I'm not able to get the data list 
@SerializedName("data")
   public List<Data> data;

   public List<Data> getData() {
       return data;
   }

  public class Data {
   @SerializedName("details")
   private Category_name category_name;

   public Category_name getCategoryName() {
       return category_name;
   }
}

   public class Category_name {
       @SerializedName("category_name")
       public String name;

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }
   }

@Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(NewsViewHolder holder, int position) {
       Log.e("Its coming","NewAdapter");
       ApiObject apiObject = apiObjectList.get(position);
         holder.title.setText(apiObject.getData().getCategoryName().getName());

   }
I'm not able to access the getCategoryName();

Please help thanks in advance
`````

Comment: For your new json, it should be apiObject.getDetails().getCategoryName. Also how are you parsing your json ?

Comment: In Json Category_name is string variable inside of details object. and your model class you create class of Category_name.

Comment: you are parsing way through POJO is wrong according to your JSON response or you should change your JSON response according to your POJO.

Comment: - @VivekMishra I'm not able to access  the getDetails by apiobject

Answer (score 0):

use json 2 pojo conversion to create proper model class of json data 
 http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

pass whole example object to adapter constructer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to follow these way of POJO parsing according to your JSON response.

```
 public class Data{
 @Serialization("status")
 @Expose
 private String status;
 @Serialization("data")
 @Expose
 private List<MyData> data;
```

Then

```
public class MyData{
@Serialization("details")
@Expose
private List<Details> getDetails();
@Serialization("product_count")
@Expose
private String Product_count;
@Serialization("products")
@Expose
private List<Products> getProducts();
//setter and getters
}
```

**Details POJO**

```
Public class Details{
@Serialization("category_id")
@Expose
private String category_id;
@Serialization("category_name")
@Expose
private String category_name;
@Serialization("category_icon")
@Expose
private String category_icon;
//setter and getters
}
```

**Products POJO**

```
Public class Products{
@Serialization("product_id")
@Expose
private String product_id;
@Serialization("product_name")
@Expose
private String product_name;
@Serialization("product_image")
@Expose
private String product_icon;
etc
//setter and getters
}
```

Comment: Where should i use  @SerializedName("data")

Comment: Yea i did exactly same , i have created getData() ; in the Data  class  getDetails() in the MyData class when i create a object of Data class in other class I'm not able to use getDetails()                             like data is object      data.getData().getDetails() is getting error